# How to reduce response time of server with single client and thousands of requests per second?

Tags: node.js, http, server, request

I'm trying to implement an openrtb bidder using nodejs, with 2 instances of nodejs app running at same time. 
For testing, i started a simple hello world node server and sent 100 requests per secound from same machine. But the response time takes atleast 50-200ms and varies a lot for each request.

I'm curious why it is behaving like this. I'm expecting very quick response because:
1) both server and client are on same computer
2) no processing at server, just a direct hello world response
3) server has to handle only one client

I am expecting server to handle thousands of requests from same client within 100ms.

Is there any way i can improve response time for my node server (other than using multiple instances which already tried).

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that you have something wrong in your setup.

Could you try this?

```
'use strict';

const http = require('http');

const document = Buffer.from('Hello world!');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    // handle some POST data
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        var body = [];
        req.on('data', (chunk) => {
            body.push(Buffer.from(chunk));
        }).on('end', () => {
            res.end('You posted me this: ' + Buffer.concat(body).toString());
        });
    // handle some GET url
    } else if (req.url === '/') {
        res.end(document);
    } else {
        res.end('Unknown request by: ' + req.headers['user-agent']);
    }
});

server.listen(3000);
```

They claim they can handle over [1M requests per second](https://github.com/uWebSockets/uWebSockets/wiki/(More-than)-one-million-requests-per-second-in-Node.js).

Comment: hi,  i tried same as the code you gave.  but did you meant to give code for `uwt.http.createServer ` instead of  `http.createServer   `?